SwiftUI is there any way to share a file with Whatsapp programmatically?
I'm developing an iOS app by using SwiftUI, where I want to make the users enable to share their feed photo or video with Whatsapp. Here are my codes for that:
func shareImageToWhatsapp(caption: String, url: URL) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://app") {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                    // Error handling...
                    guard let imageData = data else { return }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
                        let photoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")
                        do {
                            try imageData.write(to: photoURL)
                        } catch {
                            // Handle error if needed
                        }
                        let contentCaption = "\(caption)"
                        if let encodedCaption = contentCaption.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
                            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(encodedCaption)&image=\(photoURL)") {
                                UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.resume()
            }else {
//             TextView("Whatsapp is not installed on your phone.")
            }
        }
    }

But the above codes don't work normally. Just text not file is shown on Whatsapp share window.
Is there any way to solve that problem so to share files with Whatsapp programmatically in SwiftUI?
